# How can I filter an object based upon value in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, object

I have the below objects. Whose value is YES, I need to filter it and store it in variable.

```
"CalcResult": {
        "result": [
            {
                "IS_RPOP": "YES",
                "IS_ENE": "NO",
                "IS_SLO": "YES",
                "STATUS": "INCOMPLETE"
            }
        ],
        "Info": {
            "STATUS": [
                "INCOMPLETE"
            ]
        }
    }
```

Comment: What did you try? Where are you stuck? Please provide your attempts and we will help you find where you went wrong.

Comment: what is your expected output??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let CalcResult = {
  "result": [{
    "IS_RPOP": "YES",
    "IS_ENE": "NO",
    "IS_SLO": "YES",
    "STATUS": "INCOMPLETE"
  }],
  "Info": {
    "STATUS": [
      "INCOMPLETE"
    ]
  }
};
let arr = [];
Object.entries(CalcResult.result[0]).map((property, value) => {
  if (property[1].toUpperCase() === "YES")
    arr.push({
      [property[0]]: property[1]
    })
});
console.log(CalcResult.result[0], 'json');
console.log(arr, 'arr');
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems you want the keys and values which are equal to YES, if so you can try this method:

```js
let data ={ "result": [ { "IS_RPOP": "YES", "IS_ENE": "NO", "IS_SLO": "YES", "STATUS": "INCOMPLETE" } ], "Info": { "STATUS": [ "INCOMPLETE" ] } };
var result = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(data.result[0]).filter(([k,v])=>v=='YES'));

console.log(result)
```